# Migrate validations from strus1.3 to struts2

Tags: validation, struts2, migration, struts1

I am current working on a migration project from struts1.x to struts2. I am looking for some help in migrating the existing validations.xml and validations-rules.xml to struts2 equivalent. I am aware that we need to create validation xml per action class in struts2, but idea of placing all validations under file like in struts1 looks more better in terms of managing the application. If anybody had done similar work, please give me some pointers or guidance.

Secondly, if validation using one single file is not possible, i would like some help on how to convert the validations file to equivalent struts2. I am not able to understand the plugins part, for eg, mask, date. Seems they are more easy in struts1, whereas in struts2 we have to write regex for almost everything. for eg, i couldnt find anything for just a Invalid date validation. Whereas just using the date plugin in struts1 its possible.

Comment: It's not clear what are you trying to convert.

Comment: As mentioned above, i am trying to convert the validations.xml file from struts1 to validations in struts2